# Difference between the Sennheiser i300 and MM70i headphones for iPhone/iPod/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod, headphones

From what I can gather, the Sennheiser i300 headphones are Apple exclusive headphones, not available anywhere else, but they appear to be identical to the Sennheiser MM70i.

Can anyone shed any light on this? They look the same, are they the same internally? I can't even find the i300's on Sennheiser's site!

Here's some links:

i300 on Apple.com: http://store.apple.com/uk/product/H3559ZM/A
MM70i on Sennheiser.com: [http://www.sennheiser.com/sennheiser/...](http://www.sennheiser.com/sennheiser/home_en.nsf/root/private_headsets_mobile_music_504161)

Thanks for any info on the differences!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Huh! So I asked an Apple representative, but they didn't know. I also asked Sennheiser and they finally got back to me. Apparently the **i300** are exclusive to Apple (as I suspected), and although they look very similar to the **MM70i**, they're apparently closer in sound performance to the cheaper **MM30i**.

So basically, the Apple exclusive Sennheiser i300 are equivalent to the Sennheiser MM30i.

You can see the MM30i here:
http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/private_headsets_mobile_music_504739

According to the Sennheiser representative, the **MM70i** has a better bass response and more accessories than either the MM30i or the i300.

So, from what I can gather, it seems buying the cheaper MM30i, or the more expensive MM70i, is a better option than the Apple exclusive i300.

Update: Since I wrote this question, it appears that Apple have reduced the RRP of their i300 to match that of the MM30i. However, as Amazon seems to consistently offer a 30% discount on the MM30i's, the Apple exclusive headphones are still more expensive in a practical sense.

Answer (score 0):

I own the i300's from Apple store, and also bought the mm30i's to try as I don't like the asymmetric cable on the i300's. I returned the mm30i's (saying they were faulty) because the sound was THAT bad. No comparison, the i300's far outshine the mm30i's. Fuller sound, better better. Everything is better EXCEPT the annoying asymmetric cable. Might be worth also trying the CX400's I'm told they are similar.